# Permission denied (publickey). error appears suddenly with GitLab. I config private and public key correctly

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I have run to "Permission denied (publickey)" problem since today. Indeed two days ago all work properly.

Here some info:

I generated private and public key 2 month ago. I created a new private project 2 days ago and all worked properly. Indeed on my GitLab profile in https://.../profile/keys I can see that my SSH keys was used 2 day ago.

But now if I try to type : `ssh -Tv git@xxx`

I have a permission denied:

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxx [130.192.16.165] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to xxx:22 as 'vgit'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:g6mCwdFaFWdQG0rfBcIGGXDQNvJR0tan+sF8N53Tvow
debug1: Host 'xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:uEcoFZk1Nh6/5KRdoKFtktiOtX8qoUupC4ohwKrvvWA
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:uEcoFZk1Nh6/5KRdoKFtktiOtX8qoUupC4ohwKrvvWA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
vgit@xxx: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Why two days I had the permission and now I don't have it?

I'm using Git Bash on Window 10

Comment: The one key your client was able to offer was `Offering public key: /c/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519`. Apparently that key is not listed on the server. We can't tell you why; only the server could tell you.

Comment: How can I solve it? I tried to generate another key but it didn't work. How can check the server key list?

Comment: I'm not sure (how to solve it). The keys you gave *to* the server must be stored somewhere *on* the server, but I'm not familiar with GItLab and presumably GitLab supplies the software that does this.

Comment: The public key is stored on the server. I can see it on my profile: https://.../profile/keys. Indeed two day ago I had the permission

Comment: OK, if the key is there, something's gone wrong at the server end with *finding* (and/or using) the key there. Again, I can't tell you what or why, just that it's rejecting your use of that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the same commands today and now it works. I cannot say why yesterday it didn't work. The mystery of computer science.